# Karate embedded experssion to add XML blocks in the request payload transforms "<" to "&lt;"

Tags: karate

I have been trying to add a XML block in to XML payload, it works fine if I declare a variable with a XML block under the scenario before reading the XML file. However it fails/adds special characters replacing "<",">" if we fetch the address from Javascript function/another scenario in a different feature file.

**Below works fine:**

```
Scenario: Add address XML block
* def address = 
"""
    <Address>
              <StreetNo>2</StreetNo>
              <Street Type="Avenue">Second</Street>
              <City>ADELAIDE</City>
              <State Name="SA"/>
              <Postcode>5000</Postcode>
              <Country ISO3166="AU"/>
          </Address>
"""
* def b2bRequestBody = 
read('classpath:supportingFiles/b2bApplication_Post/CAL_11OwnsAndPurchase.xml')
```

**This approach has problem:**

**Javascript function to return XML block:**

```
function()
{
return {
fetchStdAddress1: function()
      {
       var Address =  
          `<Address>
              <StreetNo>2</StreetNo>
              <Street Type="Avenue">Second</Street>
              <City>ADELAIDE</City>
              <State Name="SA"/>
              <Postcode>5000</Postcode>
              <Country ISO3166="AU"/>
          </Address>`;
        return Address;
      },
}
}
```

**Scenario to assign XML to a variable and reading XML file:**

```
Scenario: Submit application from B2BApplication API
* def functions = call read('classpath:reusableFeatures/utils/customiseB2BRequests.js')
* def address = functions.fetchStdAddress1()
* print address
* def b2bRequestBody = 
read('classpath:supportingFiles/b2bApplication_Post/CAL_11OwnsAndPurchase.xml')
* print b2bRequestBody
```

**Excerpt of XML payload:**

```
<AddressWrapper>
<Identifier UniqueID="1655877356200" Type="BrokerAssigned"/>
    #(address)
</AddressWrapper>
```

**Result:** It is replacing "<" and ">" like below,

```
&lt;Address&gt;
    &lt;StreetNo&gt;2&lt;/StreetNo&gt;
    &lt;Street Type="Avenue"&gt;Second&lt;/Street&gt;
    &lt;City&gt;ADELAIDE&lt;/City&gt;
    &lt;State Name="SA"/&gt;
    &lt;Postcode&gt;5000&lt;/Postcode&gt;
    &lt;Country ISO3166="AU"/&gt;
&lt;/Address&gt;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#type-conversion

I think a one line change will solve your problem:

```
* xml address = functions.fetchStdAddress1()
```